# How to make variable a string in Sikuli

Tags: python-2.7, sikuli, sikuli-script

I'm using sikuli in Liunux to try to type in a password.

```
class Library(object):
    def type_password(password="")
         type ("password_picture.jpeg", password)
```

I run this piece of code by typing this into the command prompt

> java -Xmx512M -Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
>   -Dsikuli.FromCommandLine -jar ./sikuli-ide.jar -r password.sikuli  --args type_password password_name

FYI: password_name is the actual password which contains letters and numbers

I get an error that says

> **2nd arg can not be coerced to int**